# How do I create server specific variables in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I made a slash command that uses a channel selection. I'm using this to set the logging channel. I need help to have the same variable but with different values per-server.

For example:

Server 1 = #logs

Server 2 = #mod-only

I don't know how to get variables to have different values in different servers.

Right now I have this. but if you ban someone in "Server 2", it will log to "Server 1."

logchannel.js

```js
var logchannel = interaction.options.getChannel('channel');
        exports.logchannel = logchannel;
```

ban.js

```js
var logchannel = require('./logchannel');
        var logchannel = logchannel.logchannel;
        logchannel.send('message');
```

I need to figure out how to get the log channel variable to have different values throughout different servers. If anyone could answer how to do this please let me know.

I also already tried using MongoDB and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution without using mongo but you can achieve the same with mongo. There are many approaches you can take to achieve the same it's a basic one and not the best.

```
const logChannels = {
        'serverID': 'channelID',
        'anotherserverID': 'anotherchannelID',
}
var logchannel = logChannels[guild.id] // Here you will have your log channel ID
guild.channels.cache.get(logchannel).send(`message`)
```

Comment: string literals don't require the `[]`s in objects

Comment: Is there a way it could automatically be added to that by using the slash command?

Comment: you can access `interaction.guild` from interactionCreate event and check if it exists I think so it would be `logChannels[interaction.guild]`.